# build java method to change two textViews

Tags: java, android, methods, textview

I have two buttons and two textViews , when i click "add2_A" ,then "score1" is updated and increment by 2 .

the same is "add2_B" will increment "score2"

i want to use only one method for both of them ..the problem is that the app crash !

this is my java code :

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class app2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener 
{
public int number =0;
public int id;
TextView txt1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score1);
TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score2);
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app2);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
   id=v.getId();
}

public void increment2(){
    number =number +2;
    if(id ==R.id.add2_A)
        txt1.setText(number);
    if(id== R.id.add2_B)
        txt2.setText(String.valueOf(number));
}}
```

**edit** :
this is XML code for calling "increment2" method :

```
<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/points2"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:id="@+id/add2_A"
android:onClick="increment2"/>
```

**edit** : 
i solved it and it works now ..this is the code after editing :

```
public class app2 extends AppCompatActivity  {
public int number =0;
public int id;
public TextView txt1;
public TextView txt2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app2);
    txt1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score1);
    txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score2);
}

public void increment2(View v) {
    number = number + 2;
    id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.add2_A) {
        txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score1);
        txt1.setText(String.valueOf(number));
    }
    if (id == R.id.add2_B) {
        txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score2);
        txt2.setText(String.valueOf(number));
    }
}
```

**edit** :
this is what appears in the logcat and there's no other messages in the message bar :

```
  Process: com.example.mayouza.myapplication2, PID: 2553
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mayouza.myapplication2/com.example.mayouza.myapplication2.app2}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:120)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:151)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:33)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:33)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
                                                                                  at com.example.mayouza.myapplication2.app2.<init>(app2.java:11)
                                                                                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: could you attach the error message?

Comment: edited the question ..

Comment: The error doesn't come from this activity, but probably missing ComponentInfo.

Comment: can you guess what's missing ?i'm already have a GPU issue

Comment: Can you post your layout activity_app2.xml?

Comment: `increment2` is never called in your code... Put all that code into onClick. Don't store `id` as a field

Comment: increment2 is called in the XML ..i posted it

Comment: Whenever you use `android:onClick` that method must be 1) public 2) void 3) accept a View parameter. Otherwise, your code crashes

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks i could solve it using this answer i was missing the view parameter ..i need to note that the duplicated question you mentioned in the link didn't solve the problem that's why i asked again.

Comment: It actually does solve the stacktrace you've posted and the code in the question. The onClick problem is a different error completely, and also tells you that the method needs a View parameter if you read it

Comment: Note: your views aren't changing after onCreate, so you should only use findViewById once for each view, not everytime a click happens

Comment: i'm not good at reading stacktrace yet ,,and thanks for the note you're right

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to successfully call `findViewById()` before you call `setContentView()` because view hiearchy has not  built yet.

You need to move call to `findViewById()` after call to `setContentView()`.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_app2);
txt1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score1);
txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score2);
```

Comment: i did ,, the app opened but when i click the button it crashes again

Comment: post your code where you call increment2().